# Run a query from two data sets programmatically

Tags: database, excel, oracle, vba

I am trying to reconcile data from a website and a database programmatically. Right now my process is manual. I download data from the website, download data from my database, and reconcile using an Excel `vlookup`. Within Excel, I am only reconciling 1 date for many items.

I'd like to programmatically reconcile the data for multiple dates and multiple items. The problem is that I have to download the data from the website manually. I have heard of people doing "outer joins" and "table joins" but I do not know where to begin. Is this something that I code in VBA or notepad?

Comment: I'd like to add that I am using SQL, Oracle, and EXCEL. So far I am reconciling one item and one date, but of course there are many dates and many items. I'd like to reconcile everything at once rather one item and one date at a time - not sure how I should go about this programatically?

Comment: @techgurl: Do you actually have access to the database server that houses the data you are trying to compare?

Comment: Hi Rich B - yes I have access to the database server. I am trying to compare to the same data off a website to see if it matches. VBA or notepad both work - but my knowledge of programming is elementary.

Comment: @techgirl: Read my question to you very carefully. Do you have local access to the database server with the data on it? Or do you just have access to one side of the data and the other side is on a website? I think you have an issue understanding what a database server is, and we need to get this clarified.

Comment: @techgirl When you download the data from your website, what format do you get it in?  Are you getting an excel spreadsheet or something else?

Comment: I heard that I can use a schema browser to reconcile but need an excel driver -  has anyone used this? thanks!

Comment: Hi Rich, basically the data is sent to me via email and I have put it in a database. I have access to that... they also post the data online on their website via an excel sheet. I am trying to reconcile between the two sources (my database from the stuff they send me and their website). I have access to all the data - I just want to be sure they match up with what they have online as well. Thanks!

Comment: @ Joseph - I am getting a spreadsheet - but it's not formatted properly into tables

Comment: @techgirl: So what does the website have to do with anything? All you need to do is compare against a database and an excel spreadsheet.
What format does the emailed data come in as?

Comment: @ Rich - sorry you are right - I am simply downloading the excel spreadsheets from the website. The emailed data comes as a spreadsheet as well - and is uploaded to my database. The database contains say X Y Z products for 2005-2009 dates, while the spreadsheet is just X 2005-2009. Then I have to open Y 2005-2009 spreadsheet. Basically the spreadsheets from the website are not compiled ...

Comment: @techgirl: And are you just comparing between x,y and z?

Comment: @ Welbog Ok I understand. I will explain this in detail - I hope I am not giving jargon. 

1) I have a website which contains downloadable spreadsheets for individual products. 
2) I have a subscription to receive the same data for all products compiled to me as an excel sheet
3) I have put #2 in a database. I want to reconcile #1 with #2.

Comment: @techgirl: Why not just import the 2nd spreadsheet into the DB and compare it there?

Comment: @ Rich - there are over 100 items to compare with, and I am working with historical data back to 2003 or 2005 (daily data)

Comment: Why don't you parse the data with something like Python, and compare it to the data in the database?

Comment: @Christopher: Why on earth would this person use python? Why wouldn't they use something they are familiar with?

Comment: @ Rich Thanks for your help - I'll try to understand more before asking anything else. 

@ Welbog - Like I said I have never worked with databases and my knowledge of programming is just limited to an introductory college course in C++.

Comment: @techgirl: This is not at all a matter of you and your understanding. This is a matter of you being able to convey a problem coherently. Edit your question to include useful information so someone can assist you.

Comment: (deleted a lot of off-topic comments; if any context is lost, blame me)

Comment: @Marc: You did a great job summarizing all the deleted junk. Wish we could have kept some of the humor, but oh well.

Comment: "I am getting a spreadsheet - but it's not formatted properly into tables" - the ease with which you can compare each spreadsheet to the database will greatly depend on how well/how consistently the spreadsheets are formatted. Are all the Excel files in exactly the same format (= how the data is arranged on the worksheets) or are there a mixture of formats?

Answer (score 1):

Generally I do this by bulk inserting the website data into a staging table and then write select statments to join that table to my data in the database. You may need to do clean up first to be able to match the records if they are stored differently.

Answer (score -3):

Python is a scripting language.  http://www.python.org

There are tools to allow you to read Excel spreadsheets.  For example:

http://michaelangela.wordpress.com/2008/07/06/python-excel-file-reader/

You can also use Python to talk to your database server.

http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/
http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/devlin-python-oracle.html
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydb2/

Probably the easiest way to automate this is to save the excel files you get to disk, and use Python to read them, comparing that data with what is in your database.

This will not be a trivial project, but it is very flexible and straight forward.  Trying to do it all in SQL will be, IMHO, a recipe for frustration, especially if you are new to SQL.

**Alternatively:**

You could also do this by using VBA to read in your excel files and generate SQL INSERT statements that are compatible with your DB schema.  Then use SQL to compare them.

Comment: (a lot of off-topic comments deleted; summary: discussion over whether or not it is worthwhile learning a possible unfamiliar framework for a single task when familiar frameworks would suffice)